# How can i activate a service from a broadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I want to activate a service from my broadcastReceiver, this is my code but it didn't work:

```
public class PackageChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context;
Deletecontact delete= new Deletecontact();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
Uri uri = intent.getData();
String pkg = uri != null ? uri.getSchemeSpecificPart() : null;
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")&&   pkg.equals("com.alarm"))
{Log.i("action","the package is removed");
Intent service = new Intent( context, Deletecontact.class);
context.startService(service);
}}}
```

and this is the service

```
     public void onCreate()
  {

     //deletecontact();
 super.onCreate();
 }

    @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
 {
    return START_STICKY;
 //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy()
 {
 super.onDestroy();
 }
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return mBinder;
}

public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    Deletecontact getService() {
        return Deletecontact.this;
    }
}
```

I just want to call the service when the action of the broadcast is set

Comment: isn´t your "context" field empty?
i would try to start the service through the application context instead

context.startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Deletecontact.class) );

Comment: @emna : use ctx instead of context to start service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Emna when i see you code for start service you have used this code to start service.

```
context.startService(service);
```

In this code `context` this not assign like below

So before you call `startService`

```
 context=ctx;
```

Add above code after `onReceive`.

And Make sure that you have define `Deletecontact.class` this class as Service Tag in AndroidManifest.xml For Example Below :

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="xxx.yyy.zzz.Deletecontact"
         ></service>
```

Hope this will work .

Answer (score 0):

try this,use ctx instead of context for starting service and preparing Intent:

```
public class PackageChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context;
Deletecontact delete= new Deletecontact();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
Uri uri = intent.getData();
String pkg = uri != null ? uri.getSchemeSpecificPart() : null;
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")&&   pkg.equals("com.alarm"))
{Log.i("action","the package is removed");
Intent service = new Intent(ctx, Deletecontact.class);
ctx.startService(service);
}}}
```